# archaeological evidence questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

As many would know by now, I am an Atheist and a practicing scientist (and are very thankful for being made welcome here).

Would the following format for questions related to this be acceptable - and please let me know of any alternative methods:

1. Basis: Biblical text, a particular verse and any related texts
2. Related scientific phenomena or archaeological/historical precedent
3. Question, asking for specific evidence.

I am enjoying the site and would like to contribute in a meaningful manner, so i would appreciate any feedback on this.

Comment: So long as the question is primarily about the Biblical text itself, you should be fine. If not, we'll let ya know (and help you fix it) ;)

Comment: @Amaterasu-Ditto Dan.